# Не находит файл по относительному пути

Tags: java, tomcat

Я делаю свой первый тестовый maven проект, в нем есть файл properties. Если я использую относительный путь к файлу следующим образом:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/resources/property.properties")
```

или так:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("src\\resources\\property.properties"))
```

то при запуске war на tomcat не считывает данные из файла, получается null.
При этом если задать абсолютный путь к файлу `String path = "E:\\java\\Cinema\\src\\resources\\property.properties"`, все работает.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Каталог Resources по умолчанию и так должен быть в ClassPath потому попробуйте написать просто:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("property.properties");
```

Если файл вне приложения тогда так:

```
 InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator")+"тут относительный путь до файла (относительно файла запуска)/property.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

Может кому то будет полезна информация, maven почему то не видел папку с ресурсами, проблему решила добавлением в pom файл указания на папку с ресурсами

```
 <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/resources</directory>
            </resource>
 </resources>
```

После этого стал работать вариант InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("property.properties");